# Rails and SQL - get related by all elements from array, entries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have something like this:

```
duplicates = ['a','b','c','d']

if duplicates.length > 4

     Photo.includes(:tags).where('tags.name IN (?)',duplicates)
     .references(:tags).limit(15).each do |f|
      
      returned_array.push(f.id)

    end

end
```

**duplicates** is an array of tags that were duplicated with other `Photo` tags

What I want is to get `Photo` which includes all tags from **duplicates** array, but right now I get every `Photo` that include at least one tag from array.

**THANKS FOR ANSWERS:**

I try them and somethings starts to work but wasn't too clear for me and take some time to execute.

Today I make it creating arrays, compare them, take duplicates which exist in array more than X times and finally have uniq array of photos ids.

Comment: Might be able to add `group(:id).having(Photo.arel_table[:id].count.eq(duplicates.length))`.

Comment: do Photo and Tag have a HABTM relationship?

Comment: photo has many tags, tags belongs_to photo

Comment: trying group and having but not arel_table ... must read about it

Comment: is the database mySql or Postgres?

Comment: database is mysql

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find photos that have all the given tags you just need to apply a GROUP and use HAVING to set a condition on the group:

```
class Photo
  def self.with_tags(*names)
    t = Tag.arel_table
    joins(:tags)
      .where(tags: { name: names })
      .group(:id)
      .having(t[:id].count.eq(tags.length)) # COUNT(tags.id) = ?
  end
end
```

This is somewhat like a WHERE clause but it applies to the group. Using `.gteq` (`>=`) instead of `.eq` will give you records that can have all the tags in the list but may have more.

A better way to solve this is to use a better domain model that doesn't allow duplicates in the first place:

```
class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :tags, through: :taggings
end

class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :taggings
  has_many :photos, through: :taggings
  validates :name, 
    uniqueness: true,
    presenece: true
end

class Tagging < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :photo
  belongs_to :tag
  validates :tag_id, 
    uniqueness: { scope: :photo_id }
end
```

By adding unique indexes on `tags.name` and a compound index on `taggings.tag_id` and `taggings.photo_id` duplicates cannot be created.

Comment: group(:id) alwasy was give error: ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: Expression #13 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'database.tags.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by):

Comment: Are you selecting columns which are not on the photos table? Or doing something like using adding `.includes` to scope?  Its not an issue with the code provided here as you can see by this fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea3545/1

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer (my comment was a bit vague). The issue @Wordica is experiencing is a [Server Mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) which makes MySQL act like MSSQL. Every column in the select must be in the GROUP BY or used in an aggregate function. Thus `group(:id)` is in sufficient; however you could add `select(:id)` and convert this to a sub query.

Answer (score 1):

The issue as I see it is that you're only doing one join, which means that you have to specify that `tags.name` is within the list of duplicates.

You could solve this in two places:

- In the database query
- In you application code

For your example the query is something like "find all records in the photos table which also have a relation to a specific set of records in the tags table". So we need to join the photos table to the tags table, and also specify that the only tags we join are those within the duplicate list.

We can use a inner join for this

```
 select photos.* from photos
   inner join tags as d1 on d1.name = 'a' and d1.photo_id = photos.id
   inner join tags as d2 on d2.name = 'b' and d2.photo_id = photos.id
   inner join tags as d3 on d3.name = 'c' and d3.photo_id = photos.id
   inner join tags as d4 on d4.name = 'd' and d4.photo_id = photos.id
```

In ActiveRecord it seems we can't specify aliases for joins, but we can chain queries, so we can do something like this:

```
  query = Photo
  duplicate.each_with_index do |tag, index|
    join_name = "d#{index}"
    query = query.joins("inner join tags as #{join_name} on #{join_name}.name = '#{tag}' and #{join_name}.photo_id = photos.id")
  end
```

Ugly, but gets the job done. I'm sure there would be a better way using `arel` instead - but it demonstrates how to construct a SQL query to find all photos that have a relation to all of the duplicate tags.

The other method is to extent what you have and filter in the application. As you already have the photos that has at least one of the tags, you could just select those which have all the tags.

```
Photo
.includes(:tags)
.joins(:tags)
.where('tags.name IN (?)',duplicates)
.select do |photo|
  (duplicates - photo.tags.map(&:name)).empty?
end
```

`(duplicates - photo.tags.map(&:name)).empty?` takes the duplicates array and removes all occurrences of any item that is also in the photo tags. If this returns an empty array then we know that the tags in the photo had all the duplicate tags as well.

This could have performance issues if the duplicates array is large, since it could potentially return all photos from the database.

Comment: This is going to create a very long SQL string which cant be cached and N number of joins. I would not recommend this approach.